# Google Sheets API Timing Out

Tags: google-sheets-api

I currently have a very heavy Google Sheets workbook with about 8 sheets, thousands of rows, and complex formulas. We use this a source file for many tasks and link to this workbook from several other Google Sheets using Import Range and a 3rd party tool called Coupler.IO.

This week, the ImportRanges and Coupler Imports all started timing out and would not finish. Nothing has been changed in the source file except some minor additions of data.

This seems to be an API or Google Server Bandwidth problem, but there's really no way to confirm.

Is anyone else having similar issues? Is there a solve out there?

-Leo

Comment: Usually spreadsheets slow down when there's a look of data and formulas around. It could even be that you're approaching some of the size limits for spreadsheets https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en. I'd suggest you to split your data into several spreadsheets. Isn't this feasible?